# ASP.NET Core IdentityServer4 and Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I realize that this is all bleeding edge stuff, but I'm curious if anyone has some good resources on this topic.

In it's current state (or soon to come) can IdentityServer4 be used in conjunction with an ASP.NET Core API and a SPA app using Windows Authentication?

Comment: This will be possible. We just didn't have the time to research and document the details. Use this issue to track it: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/178

Comment: Fair enough. You folks do good work. Keep it up.